# OpenLayers - image Filter for different Layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

based on this tutorial: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-filter.html i want apply an filter to my different Layers. To achieve this goal i have an array of Group. `var groupsMap = [];` My Groups are:

- OSM
- Here WeGo Map
- Stamen Map
- Bing Map

For example for Bing Map i have:

```
function bingMaps() {
  var layers = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < bingStyles.length; ++i) {
    layers.push(new ol.layer.Tile({
      visible: false,
      preload: Infinity,
      source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
        key: KEY_BING, //'Your Bing Maps Key from http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ here',
        imagerySet: bingStyles[i]
        // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
        // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
        // maxZoom: 19
      })
    }));
  }

  var bingLayers = new ol.layer.Group({
    title: "Bing",
    layers: layers
  });

  // return bingLayers;
  groupsMap.push(bingLayers);
}
```

Every Layer is available on sidebar in this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; ++i) {
      if (groupSelected.values_.title === "Bing") {
        layers[i].setVisible(bingStyles[i] === layerSelected);
      }
...
}
```

At the end i set my filters:

```
var selectedKernel = normalize(kernels["sharpen"]);
$('.selected-filter').on("click",function () {
    var filterSelected = $(this).attr("value");
    console.log(filterSelected);
    selectedKernel = normalize(kernels[filterSelected]);
    map.render();
 });
```

For setting the filters for ALL my layers the only solution that 
it seems to work is this:

```
var layers = groupsMap[0].values_.layers.array_;
  // var layers = groupsMap.getLayers().array_;
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].on('postcompose', function (event) {
      convolve(event.context, selectedKernel);
    });
  }

  var layers = groupsMap[1].values_.layers.array_;
  // var layers = groupsMap.getLayers().array_;
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].on('postcompose', function (event) {
      convolve(event.context, selectedKernel);
    });
  }

  var layers = groupsMap[2].values_.layers.array_;
  // var layers = groupsMap.getLayers().array_;
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].on('postcompose', function (event) {
      convolve(event.context, selectedKernel);
    });
  }

  var layers = groupsMap[3].values_.layers.array_;
  // var layers = groupsMap.getLayers().array_;
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].on('postcompose', function (event) {
      convolve(event.context, selectedKernel);
    });
  }
```

In fact if i try to use a cycle:

```
for(var i = 0; i < groupsMap.length; i++){ 
    var layers = groupsMap[i].values_.layers.array_;
    // var layers = groupsMap.getLayers().array_;
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layers[i].on('postcompose', function (event) {
          convolve(event.context, selectedKernel);
        });
    }
  }
```

or:

```
for(var i = 0; i < groupsMap.length; i++){ 
    var layers = groupsMap[i].values_.layers.array_;
    applyFilter(map.getLayers().array_,selectedKernel);
  }
```

**does not work**. in particular does not work `map.render()`,method defined befor. Why ? 
Can someone help me to understand why it does not work? My first solution works but it's really bad..

Comment: The first method won't work correctly because you are using `i` for both the inner and outer for loops.

Comment: ooh Yes ! tiredness makes bad jokes. Thanks :)